# Trying to put a standard screw in drywall on wall above my window for a curtain rod but I hit something hard

Tags: drywall, curtain-rail

It looks like the whole width of my wall above my window can't have a screw deeper than 5/8". This is in an apt.

Very frustrating that I can't hang a standard curtain rod. I can only use those cafe rods because they use short screws.

Comment: You did not ask a question ... this is a Q&A site, not a chat forum

Comment: Is the construction masonry, if so that is probably steel header. just guessing. You can test that with a magnet.

Comment: You'll get better help if you post pictures.

Comment: I would not hang curtains using a "short" screw. At 5/8" that tells me it'd only be in the drywall and an anchor wouldn't even give much support as it's not really expanding behind it any.

Comment: You can hotglue the rod holder to the wall. Done right, hotglue can actually hold hundreds of pounds, and you can hair-dryer it off at move-out without getting dinged for wall damage.

Comment: Yes it's a concrete floor building. I googled the term you mentioned Steel Header and that is exactly what it is. Who on earth would have designed such stupidity because the average person doesn't have a drill.